# Type of template function without template parameters

Tags: c++

I have some code that is templated over four parameters:

1. Floating point type
2. SIMD vector length in that floating type
3. SoA (Structure of Array) length
4. Whether to use 12 parameter gauge compression (some algorithmic difference).

The unit tests looks like this:

```
#if defined(QPHIX_SCALAR_SOURCE)
  if (precision == FLOAT_PREC) {
    if (compress12) {
      runTest<float, 1, 1, true, UF, PhiF>();
    } else {
      runTest<float, 1, 1, false, UF, PhiF>();
    }
  }
  if (precision == DOUBLE_PREC) {
    if (compress12) {
      runTest<double, 1, 1, true, UF, PhiF>();
    } else {
      runTest<double, 1, 1, false, UF, PhiF>();
    }
  }
#else

  if (precision == FLOAT_PREC) {
#if defined(QPHIX_AVX_SOURCE) || defined(QPHIX_AVX2_SOURCE) ||                      \
    defined(QPHIX_MIC_SOURCE) || defined(QPHIX_AVX512_SOURCE) ||                    \
    defined(QPHIX_SSE_SOURCE)
    if (compress12) {
      runTest<float, VECLEN_SP, 4, true, UF, PhiF>();
    } else {
      runTest<float, VECLEN_SP, 4, false, UF, PhiF>();
    }

#if !defined(QPHIX_SSE_SOURCE)
    if (compress12) {
      runTest<float, VECLEN_SP, 8, true, UF, PhiF>();
    } else {
      runTest<float, VECLEN_SP, 8, false, UF, PhiF>();
    }
#endif
```

There are other instances that look somewhat similar. Since the template
parameters must be known at compile time but we want to allow the user to
choose the float, `soalen`, and `compress12` during runtime, we must use these
kind of structures.

I'd like to abstract that away. Ideally something like this:

```
call(runTest, prec, veclen, soalen, compress12);
```

Perhaps one needs to use a template for that, so it might as well be this:

```
call<ThisClass::runTest>(prec, veclen, soalen, compress12);
```

My implementation idea is something like the following, except that I do not
know what `Function` should be.

```
enum Precision {
  prec_half,
  prec_float,
  prec_double
}

template <Function func>
void call(Precision prec, int veclen, int soalen, bool compress12)
{
  if (prec == prec_half) {
    // More nested `if` constructs for `veclen`, `soalen`, ...
    func<half>();
  } else if (prec == prec_float) {
    func<float>();
  } else {
    func<double>();
  }
}
```

Is there some way to take a member function template and pass that to something
without concrete template parameters? I can sure pass
`ThisClass::runTest<float, 1, 1, false>` because that has a sensible type. What
is the type of `ThisClass::runTest`?

Comment: Template specialization?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't understand what you mean. If `runTest` was a class, that would be easy, I guess. But the thing in question is a member function template. How would that work?

Comment: _"How would that work?"_ Member function template specialization?

Comment: I don't think that template specialization is the right thing. What I want is to use a member function template with various template parameters. And I do not want to write hundreds of lines of nested `if`s like there are currently. What I just thought could be to make sure that all those `runTest` member templates have the same signature and just pass the enclosing class to my `call` function.